# CAMBIAR HWID CON C#

Tags: c#, cmd

Buenas tengo una pregunta, quiero cambiar el hwid de un periférico.

He visto que hay un comando `reg`  que se usa en cmd pero no llego a enterderlo del todo, mi pregunta es si puedo hacerlo desde c# ya que yo quiero cambiar el registro completo no solo una lina.

Actualización 1

He estado probando y he llegado hasta aquí:

```cs
string userRoot = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER";
            string subkey = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced";
            string keyName = userRoot + "\\" + subkey;

            Console.WriteLine("1- Mostrar Archivo: ");
            ConsoleKeyInfo reg = Console.ReadKey();

            if (reg.Key == ConsoleKey.D1)
            {
                Registry.SetValue(keyName, "Hidden", 1, RegistryValueKind.QWord);
            }
```

Como puedo cambiar un registro en vez de que sea un número que sea una cadena:

Quiero añadir esta linea en un registro (el registro es de texto)

```
HID\VID_1AF3&PID_0001&REV_0001
```

Pero al añadir esa linea me da un error en la parte de:

```
HID\VID.....
```

Como puedo hacerlo?

Actualización 2

He cambiado esta linea en la que pongo `MultiString` el resultado es este:

```cs
Registry.SetValue(keyName, "HardwareID", nuevacadena, RegistryValueKind.MultiString);
```

La variable nueva cadena contiene:

```cs
string nuevacadena = "HID'\'VID_20DE&PID_198A&REV_00>?&MI_01" +
                "HID'\'VID_20DE&PID_198A&MI_01" +
                "HID'\'VID_20DE&UP:0001_U:0002";
```

Donde esta la barra pongo '/' y no me detecta como fallo (no por eso esta bien pero es para probarlo), el problema esta que cuando ejecuto el programa sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solucion:

Poner un @ antes de poner la ruta

```cs
@"HID\VID_20DE&PID_198A&REV_00>?&MI_01"
```

Comment: No cambies toda la pregunta que has formulado para decir que ya lo resolviste, mejor agrega una respuesta explicando como lo resolviste y si es posible el codigo que implementaste.